# Use scalaz in console repl without creating a project

Tags: scala, sbt, scalaz

Is there any way to use scalaz by simple `scala` command in the terminal, without creating sbt project?

Comment: Coincidentally, yesterday I've put together a simple thing, that does exactly what you want here: https://github.com/folone/typelevel-activator

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either manually grab the jar or use sbt to grab the jar once and put it in your classpath:

```
#!/bin/sh
/Users/you/apps/scala/bin/scala -cp  /Users/you/.ivy2/cache/org.scalaz/scalaz-core_2.10/bundles/scalaz-core_2.10-7.0.0.jar
```

Answer (score 44):

If you have sbt installed, it is relatively quick to setup a scalaz sandbox.

First run sbt:

```
sbt
```

Then issue these commands:

```
set scalaVersion := "2.11.2"
set libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.1.0"
set initialCommands += "import scalaz._, Scalaz._"
session save
console
```

There you go, you are in the scala REPL with scalaz auto-imported and ready to be used (sbt automatically downloaded scalaz for you).
Because of the command `session save`, this setup is now permanent and you can at will go back to this same folder and just do `sbt console` to rerun the REPL with scalaz support.

Comment: +1! This saved me so much time. I only wish I had found it sooner. Once I can award the bounty, I will award it to you :)